# Sorting wordpress data in excel

Tags: forms, microsoft

I'm looking for a way to more quickly input wordpress data into excel.I need to create an overview of evaluations we receive for events, that include ratings (very satisfied etc) and sections where people can input comments etc. Right now we are inputting everything manually, sorting the data by day (it's all in the same file from wordpress) and counting how many people gave what rating. Then we enter that onto a separate sheet for each day and copy-paste the comments below, so it ends up looking something like this:

Very Satisfied 5
Satisfied 10
Neutral 4
Dissatisfied 3
Very Dissatisfied 1
Comments:I had fun!

...but with multiple questions.

Is there a way to automatically count ratings, or to input comments in certain sections, especially when we want to sort the days onto different sheets at the end?

I am not terribly wordpress or excel savvy but surely there must be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: what plugin are you using to get those ratings? how is the result output structured?

Comment: Hi Michael,Thanks for your reply. I'm using formidable forms as the plugin, with radio buttons.

Comment: please ask the developers of that plugin if it is possible and how to export the data as CSV file.

Comment: Hi, sorry perhaps my question was unclear. I have the exported data in CSV form. This is probably more of an excel question, but I wasn't able to find the stack exchange for that..

Comment: there seems to be no forum for that on stackexchange - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155487/if-i-had-a-question-with-excel-which-site-would-i-use